# Unable to set App icon in xcode 6

Tags: iphone, xcode6

I am new to IOS development. I am trying to add app icon and launch image to my project. I have added 120*120 size images to app icon. But its not showing when i am testing app in ipad. Can you please help to find suitable example of adding app icon to project in xcode 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs whenever we are not following `Images.xcassets` basic rules to add an **Icons/Images** into our project.
see the **screenshot**

[image]

and add the **Icons** for both **iPhone and iPad** see the **screenshot**

[image]

All **Icon** should be on right place with right sizes.

Hope this will help you...

Comment: does it helps then then improve this...thanks **@Tushar Patil**